# Using append in a for loop to fill a list

Tags: python

Im trying to write a basic deck shuffling program, but repeatedly get an out of bounds error when i try to call any specific index in my deck list.

```
suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "hearts", "clubs"] 

deck = []
def createDeck(deck):
    for i in range(0,4):
        for j in range(0,13):
            c = str(j+1) + " of " + suits[i]
            return deck.append(c)
```

Comment: suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "hearts", "clubs"]

deck = [] \def createDeck(deck): for i in range(0,4): for j in range(0,13): c = str(j+1) + " of " + suits[i] return deck.append(c)

Comment: Can you specify where the error occurs? It'd be helpful to see the full stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

You should return the list named as "deck" after all loops.

```
suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "hearts", "clubs"] 
deck = []
def createDeck(deck): 
    for i in range(0,4): 
        for j in range(0,13): 
            c = str(j+1) + " of " + suits[i] 
            deck.append(c)
    return deck
```

Answer (score 0):

```
suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "hearts", "clubs"]
deck = [] 
def createDeck(deck):
    for i in range(0,4):
        for j in range(0,13):
            c = str(j+1) + " of " + suits[i]
            return deck.append(c)
```

Assuming this is what you had, your deck[] will only contain one item because you returned from the function on the first step of your for loop.  Lose the return and your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want deck list without previous suits elements then define deck in the function otherwise when you will pass suits as an argument then deck will become suits list.

```
   suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "hearts", "clubs"]


    def createDeck(deck):
        deck=[]

        for i in range(0,4):
            for j in range(0,13):
                c = str(j+1) + " of " + suits[i]

                deck.append(c)
        return deck

    print(createDeck(suits))
```

Output:

```
['1 of spades', '2 of spades', '3 of spades', '4 of spades', '5 of spades', '6 of spades', '7 of spades', '8 of spades', '9 of spades', '10 of spades', '11 of spades', '12 of spades', '13 of spades', '1 of diamonds', '2 of diamonds', '3 of diamonds', '4 of diamonds', '5 of diamonds', '6 of diamonds', '7 of diamonds', '8 of diamonds', '9 of diamonds', '10 of diamonds', '11 of diamonds', '12 of diamonds', '13 of diamonds', '1 of hearts', '2 of hearts', '3 of hearts', '4 of hearts', '5 of hearts', '6 of hearts', '7 of hearts', '8 of hearts', '9 of hearts', '10 of hearts', '11 of hearts', '12 of hearts', '13 of hearts', '1 of clubs', '2 of clubs', '3 of clubs', '4 of clubs', '5 of clubs', '6 of clubs', '7 of clubs', '8 of clubs', '9 of clubs', '10 of clubs', '11 of clubs', '12 of clubs', '13 of clubs']
```